# Python Social Auth- import error when using Google Authentication

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I successfully followed along this blog entry more than a month ago:http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2014/04/tutorial-adding-facebooktwittergoogle-authentication-to-a-django-application/

When I created a new environment, and recreated the steps, I'm now getting an import error, `no module named google_auth` during template rendering.

It traces back to this line:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Login</a>
```

It looks like django is not looking in the social app for the correct template processing? Any ideas on why this is no longer working?

```
#settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (... , 'social.apps.django_app.default', ...)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2', 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.debug',
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
'django.core.context_processors.media',
'django.core.context_processors.static',
'django.core.context_processors.tz',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect')

#urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
url('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth')),
url(r'^$', 'app.views.home', name='home'),
)
```

## EDIT: Full traceback below

```
Environment:
Request Method: GET

Django Version: 1.7
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'charts',
 'social.apps.django_app.default',
 'djcelery',
 'kombu.transport.django')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'social.apps.django_app.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
 'charts.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware')


Template error:
In template charts/templates/base.html, error at line 69
   No module named google_auth
   59 :           </ul>


   60 :         </li>


   61 :         <li>


   62 :           Hello, <strong>{{ user.get_full_name|default:user.username }}</strong>!


   63 :         </li>


   64 :         <li>


   65 :           <a href="{% url 'auth:logout' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Logout</a>


   66 :         </li>


   67 :         {% else %}


   68 :         <li>


   69 :           <a href=" {% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %} ?next={{ request.path }}">Login</a>


   70 :         </li>


   71 :         {% endif %}


   72 :       </ul>


   73 :     </nav>


   74 : </head>


   75 : <body>


   76 : {% block content %}


   77 : {% endblock %}


   78 : <div id="footer">


   79 :     <center>


Traceback:
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/charts/views.py" in home
  743.                              context_instance=context)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render_to_response
  23.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  174.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  148.             return self._render(context)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  126.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  312.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  444.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  517.                 app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in app_dict
  329.             self._populate()
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  303.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  231.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py" in wrapper
  101.                     result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  101.                     not module_has_submodule(import_module(parentmod), submod)):
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named google_auth
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `url 'social:begin'...`

Comment: You are correct. it was in fact 'social:begin' in my actual html. Fixed question.

Comment: Import error can be raised due to import error in the recursive dependencies, which may not show on the django runserver log. Go into django shell and then try import the app . It will show you the correct error.

Comment: I am able to use manage.py shell and import social successfully. No errors are generated.

Comment: You have the full traceback for that import error? There's no ``google_auth`` import in ``python-social-auth``

Comment: @omab I added the full traceback above

Comment: What happens if you try ``{% url "social:begin" backend="google-oauth2" %}``? Do you have any reference to ``google_auth`` in your code?

Comment: adding backend did not help. I have no references to google_auth in my code. The last line of the traceback is where the error seems to be coming from. Django is trying to import the module based on a import lib function they have

Comment: Do you have an app named ``google_auth``? What's the full value for ``INSTALLED_APPS``?

Comment: There is no reference to `google_auth` within my django project.

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'charts',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'djcelery',
    'kombu.transport.django',
)

Comment: If you're pretty confident you've followed the directions clearly in replicating the setup, my first two suspicions are: 1.) a dependency has updated since you installed it last, and you aren't pinned to a known-safe version (it may help to go hunt for what versions were current on pypi when you first followed the tutorial; it looks like at least django has released new versions in the past month), or 2.) You had to take some troubleshooting steps that you've forgotten about to get it working last time, but which aren't included in the article (possibly a path/pythonpath issue?).

Comment: It's almost completely a dependency issue. I just can't figure out which one. A lot of my libraries have been updated since then. Like > 30. Going through and trying to figure out the combination to make this work would probably take even longer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is an option for you, I would propose to use django-allauth instead. I used both django-allauth and Python Social Auth and personally find it much easier to work with django-allauth. So if you have a chance, give it a try

Comment: This was what I had to do, unfortunately. The django-allauth library has been working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This is one difficult problem.

The error, the first line of the stack trace gives a clue: "Traceback: .... wrapped_callback ...."
The `social.apps.django_app.views.auth` view is called and is wrapped in decorator `psa`. This eventually produces the error but I think `django.core.handlers.base.get_response` is hiding the actual exception source. I think the reraise makes the stack trace incomplete at the moment.

The exception probably occurs in `from social.backends.utils.get_backend`. But it's hard to debug from a distance.

Can you comment out the try-catch around the line `response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)` in the file `django.core.handlers.base`. What is the new stack trace you get when loading the page?

Comment: I threw a valueerror this time. Charts is the name of the app

Traceback:
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  131.                                  % (callback.__module__, view_name))

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: The view charts.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: Hmm, that is less usefull than expected. I did however notice that my main suspect, the `psa` wrapper, has "recently" had an update. That commit even reads  "Refactor backend/strategy to avoid circular dependency". src: https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/backends/utils.py

That commit might not have helped or even introduce a new circular dependency problem in your setup. Now it seems this commit is used from versions 0.2.0 and up. So let me suggest downgrading you package: `pip install "python-social-auth<0.2.0"`.

BTW: what is your Django and python-social version?

Comment: django is `1.7`. I downgraded to python social auth `0.1.26` at the start of this problem in order to see if there was a recent problem with that library, however have not had success. Perhaps `0.2.0` may be better. I'll try that

Comment: My suggestion is to try a version less than version `0.2.0`, otherwise it defeats the point. And if possible try Django 1.6. In my experience many packages lag behind Django changes (although I don't expect python-social-auth to be one of those). If this doesn't work, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I downgraded to `Django 1.6`, and am now getting a new error.. Still an import error, but it's different. 

  40.         __import__(name)
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/admin.py" in <module>
  7. from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
File "//anaconda/envs/analytics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/fields.py" in <module>
  13. from django.db.models.sql.datastructures import Col

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: cannot import name Col